# Iscroll5 won't scroll horizontally, width(per slide) 100% also assign to class(multi use)

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile, iscroll

I am having some problem with Iscroll5, it is not scrolling horizontally. 
What i am trying to do.

1.) Assign to class, so i can use it multiple times( I can already do this part, by pushing array)

2.) Setting each slide as 100% width(i can already do this part, with the iscroll-fix.js)

3.) But when i combine the 2, it won't scroll Horizontally, but will only scroll vertically. Wondering if it is a CSS problem.

I am doing the above because i am loading in dynamic datas into the iscroller, so i won't know the sizes and amount.

Fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/GuCC2/28/

Here is my code.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style2.css">
     <script src="js/iscroll-fix.js"></script>
    <script src="js/iscroll.js"></script>

  <script src="js/script.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.4.min.js"></script>

  </head>

  <body>

    <script>

 $(function loaded () {

var scroller = new Array();

$('.myclass').each(function(){

    myScroller = new IScroll(this, {
        scrollX: true,
        scrollY: true,
        snap:true,
    });

    scroller.push(myScroller);
});

});
loaded();

        </script>
      <div class="myclass">
        <div id="scroller">
          <div class="slide" style="background-color:red;"></div>
          <div class="slide" style="background-color:green;"></div>
          <div class="slide" style="background-color:blue;"></div>
          <div class="slide" style="background-color:yellow;"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <br />
      <h1>Scrolls using scrollWidth fix</h1>
      <div class="myclass">
        <div id="scroller">
          <div class="slide" style="background-color:red;"></div>
          <div class="slide" style="background-color:green;"></div>
          <div class="slide" style="background-color:blue;"></div>
          <div class="slide" style="background-color:yellow;"></div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
   .slide {
        width:100%;
        height:242px;
        display:inline-block;
    }
    #wrapper, .myclass{
        height:242px;
        width:100%;
        white-space: nowrap;
        overflow:hidden;
        position:relative;
    }
    .scroller {
        position:relative;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you refresh the iscroll after adding data? After adding dynamic data , the width and height of the iscroll wrapper will change and you have to trigger it's refresh event.
    myScroller.refresh();